# Visual Studio 2017 Extensibility project templates missing in community edition?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and I checked the Visual Studio extension development box, but when I go to New -> Project -> Other Project Types -> Extensibility, there are no project templates, no matter what .NET Framework I choose?

Comment: I am looking to try out these samples: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis

Comment: Well, that says to look under C# -> Extensibility, not Other Project Types -> Extensibility.

Comment: Right! Do you happen to know where the Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool template has gone? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the extensibility templates have moved from being under "Other Project Types" -> "Extensibility" to being under language specific nodes - e.g. "Visual C#" -> "Extensibility" and "Visual Basic" -> "Extensibility".

The only current exception I know of is the Domain-Specific Language Designer template, but this is due to also move out from under the "Other Project Types" area by the time that Visual Studio 2017 and the [Modelling SDK RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/12/12/the-visual-studio-modeling-sdk-is-now-available-with-visual-studio-2017/) (See "Known Issues").